# Locking mechanism at GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working with a app that has both online datastore(GAE) and an offline datastore(HTML5 websql). So to resolve synchronizing problems, i'm trying to implement  a locking mechanism. 
It should work like a semaphore, or as master-slave mechanism. User can get the lock, and if not available, can request for it. (although starvation is possible, it is handled by an user-policy)

So is there any facilities provided in App Engine to implementing this locking mechanism.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit mechanism for locking in GAE Datastore.

However, Datastore supports transactions, so you could create (for example) a `SyncLock` entity and set a property `locked` to `true` inside a transaction.

Note that creating a `SyncLock` is not covered by transaction, but updating an existing one is. So different sessions should try to access the same `SyncLock` entity and this can only be achieved if entities have the same ID. So you should use userID as ID for `SyncLock`.

Comment: This answer will not work because the AppEngine datastore is eventually consistent.

So, thread 1 starts a transaction, set SyncLock to true, and thread 2 comes in, and still does not get the view of the data where SyncLock is true.

Comment: @Aaron, pls look at the second example - atomically creating an entity: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Uses_for_transactions

Comment: So if OP creates a sync entity in a "transactionally check if exists, then create" fashion, then he can be sure to not have collisions.

Comment: I believe I have some code that shows that this does not work, but my use case is different and much more complex than a counter.  I have a complex object where multiple people are editing it at the same time to create a new version of the object.  Making the edit transactional still allows two versions to overwrite each other.

However, I am also using python and ndb transactions.  So, again, the use case is different.

Comment: The whole point of transactions is that they can not overwrite each other. With GAE optimistic transactions, the second transaction editing the entity should fail.